# How to correctly handle exceptions in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

It is possible to retrieve the outputs of workers with Pool.map, but when one worker fails, an exception is raised and it's not possible to retrieve the outputs anymore. So, my idea was to log the outputs in a process-synchronized queue so as to retrieve the outputs of all successful workers.

The following snippet seems to work:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from functools import partial

def f(x, queue):
    if x == 4:
        raise Exception("Error")

    queue.put_nowait(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Manager().Queue()
    pool = Pool(2)

    try:
        pool.map(partial(f, queue=queue), range(6))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    except:
        print("An error occurred")

    while not queue.empty():
        print("Output => " + str(queue.get()))
```

But I was wondering whether a race condition could occur during the queue polling phase. I'm not sure whether the queue process will necessarily be alive when all workers have completed. Do you think my code is correct from that point of view?

Comment: It all looks good to me. When you are done with the `SyncManager` instance (returned by the call to `Manager()`) and its proxies (such as is returned by the call to `Manager().Queue()`), if you want to stop the manager's process, you can either call `shutdown()` on it explicitly or implicitly when you exit the `with Manager() as manager:` block. But since you are terminating right away after you are finished reading the queue, it hardly matters one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as "how to correctly handle exceptions", which is your main question:

First, in your case, you will never get to execute `pool.close` and `pool.join`. But `pool.map` will not return until all the submitted tasks have returned their results or generated an exception, so you really don't need to call these to be sure that all of your submitted tasks have been completed. If it weren't for worker function `f` writing the results to a queue, you would never be able to get any results back using `map` as long as long as any of your tasks resulted in an exception. You would instead have to `apply_async` individual tasks and get `AsyncResult` instances for each one.

So I would say that a better way of handling exceptions in you worker functions without having to resort to using a queue would be as follows. But note that when you use `apply_async`, tasks are being submitted one task at a time, which can result in many shared memory accesses. This becomes a performance issue really only when the number of tasks being submitted is very large. In this case, it would be better for worker functions to handle the exceptions themselves and somehow pass back the error indication to allow the use of `map` or `imap`, where you could specify a `chunksize`.

When using a queue, be aware that writing to a managed queue has fair bit of overhead. The second piece of code shows how you can reduce that overhead a bit by using a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance, which does not use a proxy unlike the managed queue. Note the output order, which is not the order in which the tasks were submitted but rather the order in which tasks completed -- another *potential* downside or upside to using a queue (you can use a callback function with `apply_async` if you want the results in the order completed). Even with your original code you should not depend on the order of results in the queue.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    if x == 4:
        raise Exception("Error")

    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(2)
    results = [pool.apply_async(f, args=(x,)) for x in range(6)]
    for x, result in enumerate(results): # result is AsyncResult instance:
        try:
            return_value = result.get()
        except:
            print(f'An error occurred for x = {x}')
        else:
            print(f'For x = {x} the return value is {return_value}')
```

Prints:

```
For x = 0 the return value is 0
For x = 1 the return value is 1
For x = 2 the return value is 2
For x = 3 the return value is 3
An error occurred for x = 4
For x = 5 the return value is 5
```

**OP's Original Code Modified to Use `multiprocessing.Queue`**

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Queue


def init_pool(q):
    global queue
    queue = q

def f(x):
    if x == 4:
        raise Exception("Error")

    queue.put_nowait(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    pool = Pool(2, initializer=init_pool, initargs=(queue,))

    try:
        pool.map(f, range(6))
    except:
        print("An error occurred")

    while not queue.empty():
        print("Output => " + str(queue.get()))
```

Prints:

```
An error occurred
Output => 0
Output => 2
Output => 3
Output => 1
Output => 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear and detailed answer!